# GPU access on docker.io container

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have an app that can only be run in in X11 environment with full GPU access/hardware OpenGL.

I can run it on Hetzner servers as their machines have decent GPUs.
Ubuntu desktop is installed and it has x11vnc running.

I'm thinking about putting all the desktop stuff inside of docker container and installing ubuntu server on the host.
Is there a way to give docker container full access to GPU?

Thanks!
Leonti

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979949/share-cuda-library-with-docker-container

Comment: here's a good explanation of how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container

Comment: Similar.  http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

Comment: Here is a container that uses x11vnc from docker.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run the container using privilegded status (see more at [the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration))

i.e. `docker run --privileged --device=/dev/snd:/dev/snd` etc

Answer (score 1):

You might want to also have a look at [Singularity](https://sylabs.io), an open-source container designed to give direct access to the host devices without giving root privileges to the container itself.