# How to run blackmagic inside docker?

Tags: docker

I try to use blackmagic inside docker, but not successful. Here is some output from "bmagic". Why it says "no cards found"? And how to fix?

```
$ bmagic
LOG   (2015-02-04 20:37:19) List of devices with IRQ 48:
LOG   (2015-02-04 20:37:19)    0000:27:00.0 Vendor=bdbd Device=a11b Class=0400 IRQ=48     (pin 1) Base0=df700000 (Vendor bdbd: Device a11b)
LOG   (2015-02-04 20:37:19) List of devices with IRQ 58:
LOG   (2015-02-04 20:37:19)    0000:24:00.0 Vendor=bdbd Device=a11b Class=0400 IRQ=58 (pin 1) Base0=dfd00000 (Vendor bdbd: Device a11b)
LOG   (2015-02-04 20:37:19) List of devices with IRQ 59:
LOG   (2015-02-04 20:37:19)    0000:25:00.0 Vendor=bdbd Device=a11b Class=0400 IRQ=59 (pin 1) Base0=dfb00000 (Vendor bdbd: Device a11b)
LOG   (2015-02-04 20:37:19) List of devices with IRQ 60:
LOG   (2015-02-04 20:37:19)    0000:26:00.0 Vendor=bdbd Device=a11b Class=0400 IRQ=60     (pin 1) Base0=df900000 (Vendor bdbd: Device a11b)
Warning: No cards found. Is the [blackmagic] driver loaded?
```

Comment: It might help if you explained what "blackmagic" is and what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: I try to keep my question succinct, such that someone can quickly tell whether he/she is entitled to answer. That saves time for both sides.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Black magic, clearly. :)

Comment: In that case you probably will never get an answer.

Comment: @user180574 On the other hand, I (and I bet a few other people) like to browse interesting questions that I can't answer just to see what else is out there and to learn something new.  So while being succinct can be good, being obtuse not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing @user180574 is talking about software using [particular hardware cards](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/uk/products/decklink/). So passing the host's /dev file nodes to the docker container is needed to enable the container to detect the hardware.

Related to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/579118/gpu-access-on-docker-io-container), I think the solution is to run docker like this:

```
docker run --privileged --device=/dev/path/to/dev/file:/dev/path/to/dev/file
```

Figuring out which /dev node you have to forward to the docker container is up to you though, as your question is rather anemic in that regard.

Comment: I try your suggestion, but it seems docker not happy with this. Any idea? Thanks. ==>  invalid value "/dev/blackmagic0:/dev/blackmagic1:/dev/blackmagic2:/dev/blackmagic3" for flag --device: bad format for volumes: /dev/blackmagic0:/dev/blackmagic1:/dev/blackmagic2:/dev/blackmagic3

Comment: it's supposed to be `--device /dev/foo0:/dev/foo0 --device /dev/foo1:/dev/foo1` etc.

Comment: Then I try "--device=/dev/blackmagic", this time it reports fatal. ==> FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 50e942d385869417a4378bcc51e79736b79a57e2d0535353dede3a57ea7b6f97: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/blackmagic": not a device node 
Container started.

Comment: sharing `ls -lha /dev/blackmagic*` from the host might help.

Comment: I try your last comment, seems good. I will post later for the result. Thanks.

Comment: Well, still not working but your suggestion is very helpful. I do see "/dev/blackmagic*" in docker and "lsmod | grep blackmagic" is there. So still troubleshooting. Thanks for the help.